# extLib / appllicationLayout: how can I define link node to open a page in a new tab?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

using extLib's applicationLayout control I'd like to place a link to a different application inside the `bannerApplicationLinks` node. This basically works fine using a `basicLeafNode` if it wasn't for the fact that the other application opens in the same browser tab. There apprently isn't any way to set the target for any kind of linking node control.

Before I go ahead and rebuild layout and navigator from scratch so that I can use standard link controls: does probably someone know some kind of well-kept secret how I could accomplish this task the simple way?

This limitation btw. applies to all types of link node elements available from extLib...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option you have is to use CSS (for targeting) and CSJS in the onLoad event to add the target attribute to the links. In the onLoad you select all links with a specific class (or all links inside a named element) and add the target "_blank" attribute.

Comment: what do you mean by "CSS (for targeting)"?

Comment: Manipulating my links onLoad using CSJS works better than I thought (actually I wasn't aware of the getElementsByClassName method). For the moment I'll stick to that, many thanks...

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like this is easy to add. Unlike normal links, the basicLeafNode does not seem to have a `target` attribute. If it did, a theme would allow you to set the default value of the target to "_new".

If you want to try extending the basicLeafNode, the code for the component is in **com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls** plugin, **com.ibm.xsp.extlib.tree.complex.ComplexLeafTreeNode**. You would need to add a `target` property and also expose it in the configuration files in **com.ibm.xsp.extlib.config** package (**extlib-outline_en.properties**, **extlib-outline.xsp-config** and **raw-extlib-outline.xsp-config**.

The link is written in the `renderEntryItemContent` method in **com.ibm.xsp.extlib.renderkit.html_extended.outline.tree.HtmlTagsRenderer** (bear in mind that this covers other link classes, not all of which will have a target attribute).

Comment: I was afraid someone would come up with this as an answer... Many thanks though for the rather complete list of elements; will surely save me some time. At the moment there's neither time or budget enough in that project, so most probably I'll resign to building my own layout.

Comment: basicLeafNode does have an onClick event that would allow you to use CSJS instead though (meant to add that on the answer when I was writing it, but lost that breadcrumb somewhere in the forest!)

Comment: ...on the other hand, no I don't: as I see basicLeafNode's onClick property is only rendered if the href property is empty. So I would need to mimic the entire link using something ugly like window.open() - which in turn will provoke popUp blockers etc...